# "The name is too long" when using Wget

Tags: linux, php, wget

I am trying to get a copy of the catalog. I would love to get the "List View" and "Show Object" details. The URL I am trying to `wget` is:

http://catalog.quittenbaum.de/index.php?_function=list_objects&Standort_ID_Auktion=M_115C&Language=eng&Zuschlag=&_start=0&kindOfListView=listView&

I get an error: `Name is too long, 317 chars total.`

Here is my `wget` command that does not work:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites -e robots=off --user-agent=Mozilla --random-wait --convert-links --content-disposition --adjust-extension --default-page=design-and-art-after-1945.html 'http://catalog.quittenbaum.de/index.php?_function=list_objects&Standort_ID_Auktion=M_115C&Language=ger&Zuschlag=&_start=0&kindOfListView=listView&'
```

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: Which wget version do you use? (There was a bug regarding this error, which was fixed in 2012: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21714). Your command runs fine here with `GNU Wget 1.15` on a NTFS partition (which has also the 255 character limit), but thes longest file name I got was 125 letters.

Answer (score 9):

I guess, wget tries to create a file named index.php?@#&*^@&(@!&)*&%@*&$%*@&#$%)@#&$&%whatever#.

Ext4 filename length limit is 255 chars.

Set the name of the page saved with `-O`.

```
wget -O "design-and-art-after-1945.html" ...
```

Comment: Wget is generating a file like this one for example: 

**'index.php?_function=faq_neu_form&&Objekt_ID=74173&Language=ger&redirect=index.php%3F_function%3Dlist_objects%26amp%3BLanguag.html'**


**The Result now is:**
I get one very large file (about 20MB) and nothing really to use.
For any other ideas I would be very thankful!


**Thank you so much Radoo!**

Comment: Do you have any redirects? In the past, in case of redirects, and some other cases I just managed to achieve my goal with `curl` instead of `wget`: `curl -L -k "<url>" -d <post-data> > <file>`